# Cargo fails because the peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates on SLES11

Tags: rust, ssl-certificate, rust-cargo

I'm trying to get Rust and Cargo working on a VM running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (SLES11) and get SSL errors when trying to compile the rust-by-example programs:

```
cargo --version
cargo 0.13.0-nightly (109cb7c 2016-08-19)

cargo build --verbose
Downloading rustc-serialize v0.3.19
error: unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
[60] Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Git and curl work normally on the machine. Any idea what the problem could be?

This seems to have been an issue with Cargo but should be already solved (?). I did an strace as recommended to see where it looks for certificates and got this:

```
stat64("/etc/ssl/certs/3513523f.0", 0xbffebe9c) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/etc/ssl/certs/85cf5865.0", 0xbffebe9c) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

and the two it searches are not there. I have no idea where to start with this, and which certificates would be valid/good ones, so any help would be nice.

Comment: By my searching, SLES 11 [appears to be pretty old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_Server) (*In February 2012, SLES 11 SP2 was released*). My guess is that the CA bundle you have is older as well. I'd suggest looking at how to update your system CA bundle as appropriate for your distro.

Comment: Yes, it is quite ancient. Unfortunately I am bound to it for a system (also got Haskell working on it). Ok, will have a look at updating the CA bundle.

Comment: @MichaelO: Cargo attempts to contact `crates.io`, have you checked navigating to the site with your browser of choice on this system? Or using Curl with SSL validation toward it?

Comment: Yes, curl can access the site, as well as git and Firefox (old version). It's only cargo, that has these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the local certificates and now I can download code using Cargo on SLES11.